# How to get parent block height using react-native?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native, mobile-development

I need to get parent block height, I guess I must use Dimensions.
But how can I do that?
Thanks

Comment: Get the height in the parent then pass it down as props to the child?

Answer (score 0):

You could get the dimensions using [onLayout](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/view.html#onlayout) and then pass them to the child component as props, as Tyler McGinnis said in his comment.

Comment: But if I use horizontal ScrollView instead of View?

Comment: Try onContentSizeChange  https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview.html#oncontentsizechange